# my base_url is not working although i autoloaded it..why?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form');

class user extends CI_Controller

{

    function user()
    {
        $this->view_data['base_url']= base_url();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->regester();
    }
    function regester()
    {
        $this->load->view('user_view',$this->view_data);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's "not" working?  What's the issue?  What *does* happen compared to what *you want* to happen?  Can we assume that these lines are in their respective files in their correct locations?

Comment: I hope you didn't put the $autoload array in the controller file. Anyway, use `__construct()` , not a method with the same name of the class

Comment: Your class name should start with an uppercase letter; `user` should be `User`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a proper constructor for php5:

```
class User extends CI_Controller
{
    private $view_data;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(); // necessary in CI if you declare a constructor
        $this->view_data['base_url']= base_url();
    }
}
```

> For backwards compatibility, if PHP 5 cannot find a __construct()
>   function for a given class, and the class did not inherit one from a
>   parent class, it will search for the old-style constructor function,
>   by the name of the class

Since your class is a child of CI_Controller, which has a `__construct()` method, I believe the method `User()` in your class isn't being called upon instanciation, and so does base_url()

Comment: yeah thanks that thing worked, acrually i wasnt able to call the constructor.may be this happend cause i followed the CI1 and after that the CI2 .i mixed them up.BTW thanks for helping  :)